# Can you install downloaded flatpaks via gnome-software?

Tags: games, gnome-software, 17.10, flatpak

I have downloaded gnome-games from their github wiki page (.flatpakref format) and Firefox Suggests opening the file with Software install, but when doing so, it tells me that it does not know how to handle the file

[image: Gnome software - Doesn't know how to handle file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ubuntu 17.10**

Hello pals, after [install flatpak](https://flatpak.org/getting.html) , you must enable "flatpak support" Add-ons in Ubuntu Software. To enable.

1. Open Ubuntu Software
2. search "gnome software"
3. On the section Add-ons, check "flatpak support".

[image]

If you have problems installing from [the flathub website](https://flathub.org/apps/), try searching the application by its name on Ubuntu Software directly. The applications provided by flathub will have a line like this `Source: dl.flathub.org`

[image]

Comment: limba? oh my first i've heard of that _and people complain about ubuntu pushing its own things :p_

Answer (score 0):

Those are flatpakref files that only tell flatpak what to do. They're plain text files. You nead to run:

```
flatpak install --from https://github.com/PATH/TO/FILE.flatpakref
```

There also exist flatpak packages which are the equivalent of .deb and have the extension .flatpak